# passing more than one data from servlet to jsp through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

Hi i am trying to call servlet from jsp through ajax,and return two data from servlet. But facing some problem with result data.

both pono podt are combined together at output. how to split the same to get the correct data.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#grn').blur(function() {
  $.ajax({
   url : 'callserv0',
   type: 'POST',
   data : {
    grnno : $('#grn').val()
   },
   success : function(data) {
    alert("new");
    $('#pono').val(data);
    $('#podt').val(data);
    return false; 
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  Receipt number: <input type="text" id="grn" />
  PO number: <input type="text" id="pono" />
  PO Date : <input type="text" id="podt" />
  <input type="button" id="find" value="Find" />
 </form>
</body>
```

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class callserv0 extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
 {
  //response.setContentType("text/html"); 
  //PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
  //out.println("i am in callserv0"); 
  
  String grn = request.getParameter("grnno");
    
  String pono = grn;
  
  String podt = "12/12/12";
  
  response.setContentType("text/plain");
  response.getWriter().write(pono);
  response.getWriter().write(podt);
 }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u1CK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a delimiter such as a comma(,) when you write the values to response. 
Then use JavaScript method **split()**

.

```
var str = "123,2/21/2017";
var res = str.split(",");
console.log(res[0]);
console.log(res[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you! for quick help. Its works!. accepted anwser.